# how to convert two level of rows into columns using python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this kind of dataframe where the column consists two level of rows. Here, I want to convert the second level of rows as columns.

```
**type_of_accident**

**accident A**           
 number                
 fatality             
**accident B**
 number                
 fatality              
**accident veh**
 number              
 fatality             
 hours
```

I expect the result will become as follow:

```
**type_of_accident     number    fatality   hours**

**accident A**         
**accident B**
**accident veh**
```

how can I make it using python?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) if `s` is `Series`:

```
df1 = s.unstack()
```

Or if `df` id `DataFrame` with column `col`:

```
df1 = df['col'].unstack()
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to `pivot` your table, which can be done with

```
df.pivot(index="type of accident", columns=["number", "fatality"], value=["another column which you want to make the rows out of it"])
```

You can get more info about pivoting [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)